# How to stop direct url based access to directory's static files(pictures) in ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have an ASP.NET webforms app running on ASP.NET 4.0. There is a subfolder with pictures in it. I do not want users to directly access these pictures from the url, instead they will use the website. In the website, there is a `gallery.aspx` page which shows the pictures.

I have configured the `web.config` file with the following config. This file, I kept inside the sub folder which I want to protect.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <authorization>
            <allow />
            <deny users="*"/> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But I can't figure out what to write with the 'allow'. This website does not have any login page, so no role is there. Can I use `gallery.aspx` page name here?

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question!

Ok, the first thing here is to think about a file path, and then BE VERY aware of two things:

When you reference a file name by "URL" or web stuff in the markup?

You are using valid URL's.

Say I have this folder with some pictures:

[image]

so, the path name to the pictures is

```
/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg
```

And, when you launch/run the web site, then the path name would look like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/Content/Fighers/F35.jpg.
```

And if I want a picture on the page, then I might have this:

```
        <img src="/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg" />
```

or even maybe this:

```
        <img src="~/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg" />
```

But, WHAT happens when you use your code behind (c#, or vb.net)?

You ALWAYS use good old fashioned plane jane windows file names!!!!

We often don't give the above much thought. but, if in code I want to read, or open the above file in code? We have to translate the web url to a plane jane REAL VALID file name. In other words:

```
web stuff, web controls, web markup = WEB URL

code behind = plane jane every day file path names!!!
```

So, in code, if I was to read/see/use/play with the above URL and read the file?

I might have this:

```
    Dim strwebURL As String = "~/Content/Fighers/f35.jpg"

    Dim strFile As String = Server.MapPath(strwebURL)

    Debug.Print(strFile)
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\AlbertKallal\source\repos\MyCalendar\Content\Fighers\f35.jpg
```

So, I wanted to make a BIG CRYSTAL clear point:

With code behind, you are NOT using URL's. And code behind uses windows plane jane file path names. And code behind DOES NOT CARE about IIS AND WEB security, and ignores that IIS WEB security. and that includes logon information!!!

What this means is this:

You can VERY easy setup security for a folder (even if your site does NOT have logons).
And once you do setup security - say no valid URL's allowed?

Then you can STILL DISH out the files, but you now have to use code behind!

Lets use a simple (and cool) real example.

I have a grid, and I want to display some pictures.

I have a table, and it has some columns, but ALSO a URL to a folder with the picture.

The data looks like this:

[image]

So, just a few rows, and it ALSO has a web based URL.

So, I can drop in a grid like this:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust"  />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnImage" runat="server" Height="68px" Width="149px"
                            OnClientClick ="popimage(this);return false"
                            ImageUrl = '<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />                               />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Note how I have a image control. I just set the expresison to the folder - but NOTE CLOSE this is web based.

The code is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Fighters", conn)

            conn.Open()
            Dim rstData = New DataTable
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
            GridView1.DataSource = rstData
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

And of course I can hover my cursor over cute picture, and see/get/have the correct URL to that picture.

In fact, I can right click - copy link. I actually get this link:

```
 https://localhost:44392/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg
```

And if I paste in above, I will see + get the picture directly.

But, we don't want users to have ANY rights to that folder, right.
(and even if you don't have security and logons, we can do this).

so, lets add security to that folder. Just drop in a web config file, and put this in:

Note this config file is dropped into the Fighters picture folder.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Ok, so now no users - and NO URL's are allowed. If I run the page I see this:

[image]

And if I even type in that full url to the image page (not the web page), I get this:

[image]

Ok, great!!! - we now can't type in the URL to that folder.

But, remember that little lesson I talked about:

```
code behind does not use the WEB based URL's
```

In fact, that plane jane code behind can get/grab/use ANY file on that computer, and in fact even other computers on your network. Code behind DOES NOT use nor care, or even respect the web security settings. And it does even care about user rights, or logged on users (if you had them, and your site had logons).

In other words, IIS security ONLY applies to web based URL's, but NOT code behind.

So, now we need to make our grid (or any code) that is to display a image.

How?

Well, in place of a URL, you now can (quite much have to) use code behind, and "stream" out the picture to the web page.

And same goes if you want say a list of files to download, you have to have some type of means or list (like say our database table).

So, what the code behind will do?

It will read the file from disk, and push/send or so called stream the file out to the web page.

This of course DOES mean that the folder of PDF's or pictures now MUST use code, since we took away rights from the web server. But as noted, your code behind that runs is not really any different then desktop code you write in .net. It does not care, and never did!!!

So, for the grid example? Well, need to have code now fetch the picture. And so like all grid view formatting, we use the row data bound event.

So, our code has to:

```
' get the row data
' get the web URL
' translate to that standard plane jane windows file
' stuff the picture into the image control.
```

this works:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim btnImage As ImageButton = e.Row.FindControl("btnImage")
        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        Dim strURL As String = gData("ImagePath")
        Dim sFile As String = Server.MapPath(strURL)

        Dim MyBytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(sFile)
        btnImage.ImageUrl = "Data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(MyBytes)

    End If
```

So, say you have a image, and to "shove" the image into the control on the page, then you use this code:

```
  dim strURL as string = "~/Content/Fighters/f35.jpg"
  dim strFile as string = Server.MapPath(strURL)

  Dim MyBytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(strFile)
  btnImage.ImageUrl = "Data:Image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(MyBytes)
```

Now, the OTHER common setup is you have a link or button or whatever, say to download a PDF file for example?

Then your code will look like this:

```
  Dim binFile() As Byte
  Dim strConType As String = ""
  If File.Exists(strInternalFile) Then

        strConType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(strInternalFile)

        binFile = File.ReadAllBytes(strInternalFile)
        Response.ContentType = strConType
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(strInternalFile))
        Response.BinaryWrite(binFile)
        Response.End()
```

So, now users cant touch, see, download, or type in a url to the file. but you code behind still don't care, and CAN EASY read that file.

So, hopefully you have some grid, or data base, or whatever for this folder of files, and can present the user a grid, or some such. When they click on that link to download a file, use above code (it will download just like any other file)

For pictures, again, they can't type in a URL. And in fact they will NEVER EVEN know the URL.

Also, in place of using security, you can also just move the folder out side of the wwwwroot (the project folder). Move it down one level lower. Then you don't need secure, but once again, code behind has no such restrictions, and does not care about IIS security - its plane jane windows code, and plane jane file paths are used.

I mean you might have some other big server, or file server - you can read/see use such files from code behind, but web urls are limited to ONLY valid path names and folder that are part of your web project folders.